# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. want to select all columns of the row button clicked on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

All I want to do is when A user clicks on "See more" button on gridview, He will get all the columns of the row button clicked on detailView1.. But I dont know where Im going wrong. Im working on C# asp.net
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        DetailsView1.Visible = false;
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT cars.carid,  cars.make, cars.model, cars.condition, cars.amount, img.img FROM cars INNER JOIN img ON cars.carid = img.carid ", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda1.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

protected void Button2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
        {
            Label lblshow = (Label)GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("carid");

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from cars where carid='" + lblshow.Text + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda1.Fill(dt);
            DetailsView1.DataSource = dt;
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Width="1000px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8" CssClass="Grid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr">
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle><PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>Select</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="See more" OnClick="Button2_Clicked" />
             </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>Image</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("img") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("img")) : string.Empty %>' alt="image" height="100" width="150"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

IsPostback on the page load event. Hope your problem get resolved.